# Unity visual studio UWP build errors building to xbox

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, xbox

**Unity version 2022.1.22f, Visual studio 2019 16.11.22**

After building my unity project to UWP with il2cpp, i follow the windows xbox uwp deployment, but when i try to build it, i get errors.

**Here is a screenshot of the errors themselves,**
[image: Errors]

**Here is the build output:**

```
1>
1>Invocation was: Executable: "D:\Visual studio\Community 2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe"
1>Arguments: "D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\Source\lumpedcpp\Lump_libil2cpp_vm.cpp" /nologo /c /bigobj /W3 /Z7 /EHs /GR- /Gy /utf-8 /wd4102 /wd4800 /wd4056 /wd4190 /wd4723 /wd4467 /wd4503 /wd4996 /wd4200 /wd4834 /wd4722 /Od /Zc:inline /RTC1 /MDd /DWINDOWS_UWP /DUNITY_UWP /DUNITY_WSA_10_0 /DUNITY_WSA /DUNITY_WINRT /DPLATFORM_WINRT /DNET_4_0 /DUNITY_AOT /DIL2CPP_MONO_DEBUGGER_DISABLED /DGC_NOT_DLL /DRUNTIME_IL2CPP /DIL2CPP_ENABLE_WRITE_BARRIERS=1 /DIL2CPP_INCREMENTAL_TIME_SLICE=3 /DIL2CPP_DEBUG=1 /DBASELIB_INLINE_NAMESPACE=il2cpp_baselib /DIL2CPP_DEFAULT_DATA_DIR_PATH=Data/il2cpp_data /DBASELIB_USE_DYNAMICLIBRARY=1 /D_WIN32 /DWIN32 /DWIN32_THREADS /D_WINDOWS /DWINDOWS /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS /DNOMINMAX /D_DEBUG /DDEBUG /DIL2CPP_DEBUG=1 /DWINDOWS_SDK_BUILD_VERSION=22621 /D__WRL_NO_DEFAULT_LIB__ /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP /I"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\libil2cpp" /I"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\libil2cpp" /I"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\external\bdwgc\include" /I"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\external\xxHash" /I"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\external\baselib\Include" /I"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\external\baselib\Platforms\UniversalWindows\Include" /I"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\libil2cpp\pch" /I"D:\Visual studio\Community 2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\winrt" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" /Fo"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\build\obj\il2cppOutputProject\x64\Debug\libil2cpp\11A0BDF31787E9DFF371F2BC88A6BFA5.obj" /Fd"D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\build\obj\il2cppOutputProject\x64\Debug\libil2cpp\11A0BDF31787E9DFF371F2BC88A6BFA5.pdb"
1>EnvArg key: PATH value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;D:\Visual studio\Community 2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX64\x64
1>
1>   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
1>   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
1>   at il2cpp.Compilation.CompilationDriver.Run(RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, ReadOnlyCollection`1 matchedAssemblyMethodSourceFiles)
1>   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(46,5): error MSB3073: The command ""D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\\IL2CPP\build\deploy\il2cpp.exe" --libil2cpp-static --compile-cpp -architecture=x64 -configuration=Debug -platform=WinRT -outputpath="D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\\build\bin\x64\Debug\GameAssembly.dll" --data-folder="D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\\build\bin\x64\Debug\\" -cachedirectory="D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\\build\obj\il2cppOutputProject\x64\Debug\\" -generatedcppdir="D:\Unity\MiningGame\Builds\UWP\1.0\Il2CppOutputProject\\Source"  --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --baselib-directory="D:\Unity\Editor\2022.1.22f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\MetroSupport\Players\UAP\il2cpp\x64\Debug" --avoid-dynamic-library-copy --dont-deploy-baselib --profiler-report --additional-defines=WINDOWS_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA_10_0 --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA --additional-defines=UNITY_WINRT --additional-defines=PLATFORM_WINRT -dotnetprofile=unityaot-win32 -verbose --relative-data-path=Data/il2cpp_data" exited with code 4.
```

I was trying to build the xbox, but it doesnt even make it to the visual studio pin, just fails.

Comment: There's a simlar issue for this on Unity website, fixed in `2022.1.23f1` [Unity Website](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/il2cpp-windows-builds-fails-when-using-vs-2022-17-dot-4-0-preview)

Answer (score 0):

H!

The linker is unable to find the "libc++.lib" library. This library is a part of the C++ standard library and is typically included with the C++ compiler.

The error message also shows that the linker is looking for the library in the "D:\Visual studio\Community 2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\lib\x64" directory, but it is not found there.

This issue might be caused because you are missing the VC++ runtime libraries or the SDKs installed on your machine. You can try to install the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019 from the official Microsoft website.

or

Make sure that the correct path to the library is specified in your project's linker settings.

Hope this helps.